# how to fix this is node"Error: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required. password: Path `password` is required."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a new user and checking whether the user email previously exists or not. If not then it is creating a new user and saving it. What do I need to correct this validation error I am getting?

I have already tried by setting name as not required. But it still does not work.

This is my User model.

User.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

const User = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema)
export default User
```

this is my router file

```
import User from '../model/User.js'
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

//register
router.post("/register",async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const newUser = new User({
            username:req.body.username,
            password:req.body.password,
            email:req.body.email
        })

        const user =await newUser.save()
        res.status(200).json(user)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})

export default router
```

this is my app.js

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import UserRoute from './routes/User.js'

const app = express()
dotenv.config()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use("/api/auth",UserRoute)

app.listen(PORT , () => console.log(`backend started on ${PORT}` ))
```

i also just notice one thing if i tries to bcrypt the password and then use it in my route then after making request in postman instead of error message i am getting null object {} in postman what's the reason ???

what is the issue on the code i tried different ways to fix this by taking reference from stack overflow but didn't work

thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is probably with the client. You are not receiving the body parameters. Can you post the client code where you make the `/register` call?

Comment: at a time i am not using the /register call in client side but just testing it in postman and posted my code here : https://github.com/priyanshu740/BlogApp @LucaPizzini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your request body look like?
Are you sure there are req.body.username and req.body.passwords?
Try console.log them before you save the user and check they are not undefined.

Comment: i tried console.log and getting something like this "{ profilePic: '', _id: new ObjectId("617adafb9a72afe72be527bf") }" @Sefi R

Comment: That's your problem. The request doesn't have username, password and email. So, what you actually did is assign undefined to them and tried to save. 
You need to add raw/JSON to the request body in postman, the JSON should look something like:
```
{
   "username": "username",
   "password": "password",
   "email": "username@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: ahhh thats very silly mistake though . i was using raw/text btw thanks for your help :)